# Class cast exception from Double to double

Tags: java

Why class cast exception from Double to double?

Used like:

```
Console.writeLine(Validator.TryParse("1.5", double.class));
```

Code:

```
public static <T> T TryParse(Object ConvertFrom, java.lang.Class<T> ConvertTo) {
        switch(ConvertTo.getSimpleName().toLowerCase()) {
            case "int":
            case "integer": return ConvertTo.cast((int)Integer.parseInt((String)ConvertFrom));      
            case "string": return ConvertTo.cast(String.valueOf(ConvertFrom));             
            case "double": return ConvertTo.cast((double)Double.parseDouble((String)ConvertFrom));              
            case "float": return ConvertTo.cast((float)Float.parseFloat((String)ConvertFrom));              
            case "long": return ConvertTo.cast((long)Long.parseLong((String)ConvertFrom));          
            default: return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah I'm sure :S What do you mean if I'm sure.. C++ doesn't have "Object".. or String. C# yeah but C# is string not String.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I was wondering too, but `java.lang.Class<T>` leaves no doubt ;-)

Comment: The `Console.writeLine` threw me off... I thought it was C#: it allows both `string` and `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing primitives and boxed primitives. Calling `TryParse("1.5", Double.class)` will work fine (and you can remove all the unnecessary primitive casts like `(int)` `(double)` etc).

The problem you encounter is that `Class#cast` first checks `Class#isInstance` and:

```
Double.class.isInstance(1.0);
```

is true but:

```
double.class.isInstance(Double.valueOf(1.0))
double.class.isInstance(1.0d)
```

are false as explained in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29)

> If this Class object represents a primitive type, this method returns false.

Bottom line: `primitive.class.cast()` will always throw an exception.

Comment: K so you're telling me the "Boxed" version of a primitive cannot be cast to the primitive type? Are you serious? C# allows this.. What is the other way then.. Make a separate case for both? Doesn't make sense to do that :S

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames: You can't call `.class` on a primitive type.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames It can't be cast the way you do it `double.class.cast(Double.valueOf(1.0d));`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes you can - try `System.out.println(double.class);`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes you can. Any java compiler allows it. It simply returns int for the Class.getSimpleName();

I still do not see why both are not castable back and forth if: Double J = 10; double I = J is an implicit cast/conversion and it works..

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames I have added some reference. And to answer your first comment, you don't need a case for each - simply handle `Double` and `double`s will get auto-boxed.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames - The other way is to use `Double.doubleValue()` or `Integer.intValue()`...

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames - **Why on earth** do you want to implement such a method???!!??

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames You can implicitly: `double d = Double.valueOf(1);`, explicitly: `double d = (double) Double.valueOf(1);`, but you can't call `double.class.cast()`.

Comment: @jahroy Why on earth does java not have TryParse?

I ended up doing: http://pastebin.com/M5E2fueG
The above works..

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames - Different languages have different features.  When you try to treat one language like another, you get into trouble.  Also... To my knowledge, `TryParse` is a method that is used to parse strings as numbers... Not to convert any random _Object_ into any kind of number.  **Also not to mention** that implementing your own TryParse (that actually works like C#'s) would be super super trivial and easy.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Honestly, I find `Validator.TryParse("1.5", double.class)` (with all the code that goes with it) much more complicated than `Double.parseDouble("1.5");` but it might make sense for your use case (actually if you explained what your ultimate goal is, you might find that there is a different way).

Answer (score 1):

If you still need to define the class each time you call the validator, why don't you just use the valueOf method of each class? The Object classes such as Integer and Double will be able to handle the primitives and return objects...

As it's been asked before, are you sure you need to implement this? You might want to review your design.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as below, Note the Caps in **`Double`**.

```
Console.writeLine(Validator.TryParse("1.5", Double.class));
```

Comment: But I'd need a separate case for "Double" and "double"

If the types are not castable, then how can I do:

Double J = 10; double I = J? That's an implicit cast and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Double.doubleValue()` and `Integer.intValue()`.

More reading:

- [Double.doubleValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleValue%28%29)
- [Integer.intValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue%28%29)

**Except....**

Your method wants to return an Object, so you can't return primitives.

---

Editorial:

It seems like you're trying to do something that is very unnatural and un-Java (Java is a typed language for a reason).